# Where does the Yoast SEO plugin set the Open Graph metadata?

Tags: search, ssl, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, open-graph

The Yoast SEO plugin add this line to the head section of the page:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://link.to.image.jpg" />
```

But according to [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly https?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910877/3416774), the line should be:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://link.to.image.jpg"/>
```

How can I locate this line to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think http and https would have matter, https is like a standard nowadays, in order to check properly, please try the following:

1. Check your image link and make sure it is working
2. Visit this FB debugger page - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and check if something else is wrong.

Comment: I know that it shouldn't be a problem, but it is. I've spent 2 days for this bug

Comment: @Ooker Could you try to post a link to your image or send the url of the page you worked on so we can find out accurately what went wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I ask a new question here, you may want to see: [Why can't Open Graph checker detect Open Graph data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57529664/3416774)